# 5px Bottom Margin Added Below Header Image

Tags: css, margin

summer-band.com

I know this can be removed using line-height:0; on my #navigation , but that throws the entire nav out of whack. Trying to find other solutions to remove hits 5px margin (only on Firefox/ mobile... doesn't show up in Chrome/ Safari.)

Comment: Well first off your HTML is invalid. Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the navigation/sidebar that is causing this. I suggest you set the navigation to `position: absolute`. Then you'll just need to move the header image to the left. Preferably, include the header and navigation inside the container.

EDIT: Next thing to do is this:

```
#container {
width: 560px;
padding: 0 130px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
z-index: 5;
height: auto;
min-height: 600px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1.0;
position: relative;
}
```

I've added margin: 0 auto, float: none (but instead of that, just remove the float), padding and position: relative. The last step is to move the navigation and header inside the container, so that the navigation is positioned relative to the container.

Finally, add this to the navigation styles:

```
left: 0;
```

Comment: That worked amazingly for the problem. Thank you.

Sadly, this caused another issue where the main container is no longer centered, any advice on fixing this new issue?

Comment: I've added some changes above.

Comment: One other change I recommend is to change the width of the container div to 600px, because at the moment it's not as wide as the contents (which are 560px wide + 20px left + 20px right). Padding (and borders) add to the overall width of an element.